# Retaining state of navigation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to retain the state of a navigation accros multiple pages pages.I have managed to get the indexes of each element I want to retain , the problem is setting them.For some reason only some of the elements seem to be set.

I have debugged the code and it seems as if only one element gets taken into consideration sometimes.I can not figure out what am I doing wrong here.Here is my code:

```
<ul id="ProductNav">
          <li>
              <h2><a href="#">@category.Key.ToUpper()</a></h2>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/arrow.gif")" class="arrow"/>
                      @Html.ActionLink(subcategory,"Index" , "Products" , new { subcat = subcategory} , null)
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
     ......
 var menuState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["navigation"]);

 for (var i = 0; i < menuState.length; i++) {
        var menuIndex = menuState[i].eq;
        $("ul#ProductNav li").eq(menuIndex).children("ul").css("display", "block");
 }
```

menuState will we an object containing an array of indexes
From what I understand so far the problem begins here:

```
$("ul#ProductNav li").eq(menuIndex).children("ul").css("display", "block");
```